# Automatically import models on Django shell launch

Tags: python, django

I'm tired of typing `from account_import.models import ImportFile` every time I open my Django shell. Is there a way to automatically run this command whenever I fire up my shell?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

install django-extensions, one of the commands it features (shell_plus) is providing the context for your models.
https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions

So, instead of `./manage.py shell` you can use `./manage.py shell_plus` so that everything is imported.

Comment: Hmm. I installed django-extensions but it said `Unknown command: 'shell_plus'` when I tried to do `./manage.py shell_plus`.

Comment: Don't forget to add 'django_extensions' to your INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: and do you know such SHELL which will keep track of all updates which happen to the database in real time without need for restarting?

Comment: That's right, add 'django_extensions' to INSTALLED_APPS, _not_ 'django-extensions' -- underscore, not hyphen.

Answer (score 8):

http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP

If you set the environment variable `PYTHONSTARTUP` to a file, this will be run first whenever you start a python shell.

Comment: oh, ok. I didn't know about django's shell. But django is definitly on my list of stuff to check out!

Comment: it loaded the file but didn't load it within the same namespace/context of the shell. disclaimer: i'm python&django newbie

Comment: This actually worked perfectly in my case. I use virtualenvs. In the `postactivate` script, I added an alias to first export the `PYTHONSTARTUP` variable, then run the django shell.
The startup script only executes when I use this alias. The only downside is if I run this alias, then in the same terminal, close the django shell, and try to open normal python shell, it will read the startup file again. But I never do this anyway. So I can live with it.

Comment: Finally an answer that doesn't require to install additional components. For the record you need to create a file imports.py like `from myapp.models import *`. Then launch the shell with this `PYTHONSTARTUP="imports.py" python3 manage.py shell`

Answer (score 0):

Create a `file.py` file in the same directory as `manage.py` file with all imports that you need.
For example:

```
from django.core.cache import cache; from django.db.models import Prefetch, Count, Q; from django.db import connection, reset_queries; from datetime import timedelta; from django.utils import timezone;
```

Then, every time after you launch the shell, simply import that file: `from file import *`