# How to run arbitrary code when django shell starts?

Tags: python, django, debugging, django-shell

This question: [Automatically import models on Django shell launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863301/automatically-run-code-on-django-shell-launch) has answers explaining how to import models upon start by using shell_plus, but no answer about how to run code in general.

But is there an easy way to just run a python script?

```
python manage.py shell [or shell_plus] --run=script.py
```

Would just run the script as if you'd typed the whole thing in as the shell started.

I realize that you can import things in the shell, but then they're stuck within a namespace.

I would think ipython should have a way to run a script, and then import its `locals()` into the toplevel namespace.  In that case you could just do `%magic script.py` and we'd be down to just one step, which would be good.

Changing the way you start the shell should be fine - the main goal is to just be able to create a file that's run on startup of the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there's a flag you can use, but if you have ipython installed it should be as simple as:

`ipython`

Then when you're in the prompt:

`run script.py`

Then:

`run manage.py shell`

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own custom command just like `shell_plus` has done: see the [source](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/django_extensions/management/commands/shell_plus.py) of the `shell_plus` command to see how. In that code you can specify and run the file that needs to be executed before starting the shell. Also useful is Django's documentation on [creating custom commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use environment variable PYTHONSTARTUP.
Also try django-extensions: [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/django_extensions)

See django-extensions/management/commands/shell_plus.py command.

From source code of this command I see that it respects PYTHONSTARTUP env variable.

Comment: the problem is that I might not want it to be run for all shells - I use ipython for things other than django!  and shell_plus only loads models.

Answer (score 2):

shell_plus uses a limited form of IPython which doesn't process its startup & configuration, which defeats most normal attempts to run things at django+ipython shell startup.  You can switch it to use the full version which will solve most problems.

**Modify django_extensions/management/commands/shell_plus.py**

remove:

```
embed(user_ns=imported_objects)
```

and replace it with:

```
from IPython import start_ipython
start_ipython(argv=[], user_ns=imported_objects)
```

Then your python code in the startup directories will be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the easiest way is to run
`cat myscript.py | awx-manage shell`

For reference, see https://github.com/ansible/awx-operator/blob/7d2d1b3c5e3766966bfec0f9f58037f654b93b59/roles/installer/tasks/initialize_django.yml#L21-L24