# With the bpython shell, how do I preload imports when the shell starts up?

Tags: python-3.x, django, shell, import

I'm using Django 3.2, Python 3.9 and bpython==0.21 for a more useable shell.  However, I notice when I start using my shell, I always have to run the same import commands

```
$ python manage.py shell
>>> from cbapp.models import *
>>> from cbapp.services import *
```

I like the bpython shell and would prefer to continue to use it, but is there a way that the imports can be run prior to the shell loading so I don't have to type (or scroll to) them each time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically import models on Django shell launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863301/automatically-import-models-on-django-shell-launch)

Comment: IT seems like that answer relies on django-extensions, which in turn relies on using "python manage.py shell_plus".  As I want to continue to use bpython, I'm not sure how that interacts with the extensions package.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11124610/6759844) might help. Tested it and works with bpython

Comment: Yup, that seems to work for me as well!